# VBA Send/Pull Data from External Workbook -- Interesting Issue

Tags: vba, validation, reference, refresh, external

I have a rather interesting problem going on in my excel problem. Basically I have two Workbooks, lets say

**ACTIVE**.xlsm and **EXTERNAL**.xls

**Active** has a macro that opens **external** and drops in some data from **active**, then reads a solution on **external** and returns it to the user on the **active workbook**. Whew. Thats a tough one. Now that we're through that, heres the problem. It is my personal opinion that there is a glitch in **external** (which I'm unable to fix as its a company read-only file) that when **active** drops in its data into a specific drop-down (data validation) cell (other data validation cells work fine with this macro, its only this one that doesn't), the solution cell on **external** doesnt update, but rather jumps to "#N/A". At this point, my VBA has run into a bug, and the code stops with **external** still open. When I look at **external**, I've deduced that this singular variable cell is the problem amdist all the other variable cells determining the solution.

The variable cell at this point contains the number "150" and although the data validation allows for this option, the solution cell still says "#N/A". It isn't until I physically click inside of the cell with "150" like I'm going to edit it, then I press enter, that the #N/A corrects to the appropriate solution (Let's say this solution is "$352.08") Keep in mind, the value within the variable cell never changed, it perhaps only was "refreshed".

Any ideas as to why this is happening? I know this is long-winded, but I suppose that's why I have been unable to find a solution thus far. Perhaps there's a VBA workaround that can simulate clicking in the cell, then pressing enter, who knows!

Thanks in advance!

Here's some code for funsies, though I don't believe this is a code issue, as it works for all other "**external**"'s that I've been working with.

```
...ElseIf Left(Range("C9").Value, 4) = "LA23" Then

CurWkbk = ActiveWorkbook.Name

PartNo = Worksheets("LINAK ONE").Range("C6").Value
PartNoID_B = Worksheets("GPL Pull").Range("B8").Value
PartNoID_C = Worksheets("GPL Pull").Range("C8").Value
PartNoID_D = Worksheets("GPL Pull").Range("D8").Value
PartNoID_E = Worksheets("GPL Pull").Range("E8").Value
PartNoID_F = Worksheets("GPL Pull").Range("F8").Value
PartNoID_G = Worksheets("GPL Pull").Range("G8").Value
PartNoID_H = Worksheets("GPL Pull").Range("H8").Value
PartNoID_I = Worksheets("GPL Pull").Range("I8").Value
PartNoID_J = Worksheets("GPL Pull").Range("J8").Value
PartNoID_K = Worksheets("GPL Pull").Range("K8").Value

Workbooks.Open ("EXTERNAL.xls")
Workbooks("EXTERNAL.xls").Sheets("Price").Activate
Range("E9").Value = PartNoID_B
Range("G9").Value = PartNoID_C
Range("I9").Value = PartNoID_D
Range("K9").Value = PartNoID_E
Range("M9").Value = PartNoID_F
Range("O9").Value = PartNoID_G
Range("Q9").Value = PartNoID_H
Range("S9").Value = PartNoID_I
Range("S9").Select
ActiveCell.Calculate
Range("U9").Value = PartNoID_J
Range("W9").Value = PartNoID_K

Range("AD7").Value = "LUS"
LUSPrice = Range("AE9").Value
Range("AD7").Value = "USD"
USDPrice = Range("AE9").Value
Range("AD7").Value = "DKK"
DKKPrice = Range("AE9").Value

Windows(CurWkbk).Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Discount Calculator").Activate
Range("D5").Value = LUSPrice

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("PRICE GENERATOR").Activate
Range("C25").Value = PartNo & " Pricing | LUS: $" & Round(LUSPrice, 2) & " | USD: $" & Round(USDPrice, 2) & " | DKK: kr " & Round(DKKPrice, 2)
MsgBox "Tillykke! Pricing for the " & PartNo & " has been generated. The price has been entered into the discount calculator.", , "Pricing Generated"
Workbooks("EXTERNAL.xls").Close False...
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be using fully qualified references to cells

this is a rewrite of your code

```
...ElseIf Left(Range("C9").Value, 4) = "LA23" Then          ' which workbook/sheet ????

CurWkbk = ActiveWorkbook.Name                               ' which workbook ????

PartNo = Worksheets("LINAK ONE").Range("C6").Value          ' which workbook ????

With Worksheets("GPL Pull")
    PartNoID_B = .Range("B8").Value
    PartNoID_C = .Range("C8").Value
    PartNoID_D = .Range("D8").Value
    PartNoID_E = .Range("E8").Value
    PartNoID_F = .Range("F8").Value
    PartNoID_G = .Range("G8").Value
    PartNoID_H = .Range("H8").Value
    PartNoID_I = .Range("I8").Value
    PartNoID_J = .Range("J8").Value
    PartNoID_K = .Range("K8").Value
End With

Workbooks.Open ("EXTERNAL.xls")

With Workbooks("EXTERNAL.xls").Worksheets("Price")
    .Range("E9").Value = PartNoID_B
    .Range("G9").Value = PartNoID_C
    .Range("I9").Value = PartNoID_D
    .Range("K9").Value = PartNoID_E
    .Range("M9").Value = PartNoID_F
    .Range("O9").Value = PartNoID_G
    .Range("Q9").Value = PartNoID_H
    .Range("S9").Value = PartNoID_I
    .Range("S9").Calculate
    .Range("U9").Value = PartNoID_J
    .Range("W9").Value = PartNoID_K

    .Range("AD7").Value = "LUS"
    LUSPrice = .Range("AE9").Value
    .Range("AD7").Value = "USD"
    USDPrice = .Range("AE9").Value
    .Range("AD7").Value = "DKK"
    DKKPrice = .Range("AE9").Value
End With

CurWkbk.Worksheets("Discount Calculator").Range("D5").Value = LUSPrice          ' which workbook ????

CurWkbk.Worksheets("PRICE GENERATOR").Range("C25").Value = PartNo & " Pricing | LUS: $" & Round(LUSPrice, 2) & " | USD: $" & Round(USDPrice, 2) & " | DKK: kr " & Round(DKKPrice, 2)
MsgBox "Tillykke! Pricing for the " & PartNo & " has been generated. The price has been entered into the discount calculator.", , "Pricing Generated"
Workbooks("EXTERNAL.xls").Close False...
```

Comment: Thanks a ton @jstola! This is a great practice to keep in mind, and I've applied it to my code. Unfortunately, it still doesn't solve the problem, but it's much neater now!